# Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?

Tags: javascript

This way I could have a function that says whatever_way_you_do_this = something. Is this possible? Basically I could tell a function which variable I want to set by giving it a string that holds the name of the variable.

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate of "Get global variable dynamically by name string in JavaScript", this question doesn't say anything about the variable being global. And it matters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given:

```
var x = {
    myproperty: 'my value'
};
```

You can access the value by:

```
var value = x['myproperty'];
```

If you're looking for a global variable, then you would check its container (`window`);

```
var value = window['x']['myproperty'];
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
eval(variableString);
```

Proceed with caution as many don't recommend using `eval()`

Comment: More versatile answer. The current best answer can only access properties. This can access both plain variables and properties `eval("x.myproperty");`. Out of curiosity, why is eval not recommended?

Comment: @BryantJackson security is one big reason, you really don't want to create the possibility of arbitrary code execution on a production machine

Answer (score 5):

If it is a global variable named `myVar`, you can use:

```
window["myVar"]
```

Comment: To elaborate: function setGlobal(varName, varValue) { window[varName] = varValue; }

Answer (score 3):

The eval function can access a variable from a string containing the variable's name.

```
eval('baseVariableName'+index) = 'something';
```