# Calling a variable by retrieving the rel attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the)

I have some content scripted to show based on a user's interaction with my prototype. When they click on a certain callout I'm trying to use the `rel` tag associated with it to feed in the correct variable, but so far I've had no luck.

Here's a small example.

```
<div class='cool-btn' rel='awesome'>
Content here
</div>
```

and then

```
var awesome = 'some content';

$('.cool-btn').click(function() {
    //do stuff
    $('.other-selector').append($(this).attr('rel'));
}
```

I remember that when you were jumping in and out of variables and selectors in ActionScript (flashback!) you would throw things in brackets `[]`, but I've been unsuccessful in attempting similar things here or finding information regarding that.

Thanks for any assistance-

Comment: I don't think "rel" is a valid attribute for `<div>` elements, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What goes wrong when the code runs?

Comment: looks similar, but if it's a duplicate i'm missing the point that would help me fix this :\ @pointy, it just appends the string equivalent. in the example above it'd render a string 'awesome,' not the variable awesome

Comment: It is a dupe. Just because it is an attribute does not make a difference. Use your skills. `window[theAttrValue]` or `var myKeys = { "awesome" :"foo"}; myKeys[theAttrValue];` You should probably use a html5 data attribute and not rel.