# Condensing similar functions

Tags: javascript, html

So what I'm trying to do is convert a series of functions like:

```js
function classAClickSell(){
 if (classASupply>=1) {
  cash = cash + classAValue;
  document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
  classASupply = classASupply - 1;
  document.getElementById("classASupply").innerHTML = classASupply;
 };
};

function classBClickSell(){
 if (classBSupply>=1) {
  cash = cash + classBValue;
  document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
  classBSupply = classBSupply - 1;
  document.getElementById("classBSupply").innerHTML = classBSupply;
 };
};
```

and am trying to get them all to resemble something more along the lines of:

```js
function ClickSell(class){
 if (class.concat('Supply') >= 1) {
  cash = cash + class.concat('Value');
  document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
  class.concat('Supply')--;
  document.getElementById(class.concat('Supply')).innerHTML = class.concat('Supply');
 }
}
```

and I was wondering if there is a way to do this, I can't seem to find one. If anyone can help out or point me in the right direction I will be stocked.

Comment: first don't use reserve keyword class as argument of ClickSell function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to access the variables, assuming the variables are global in scope:

```
function classClickSell(cls){
    if (window["class" + cls + "Supply"] >= 1) {
        cash = cash + window["class" + cls + "Value"];
        document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
        window["class" + cls + "Supply"] = window["class" + cls + "Supply"] - 1;
        document.getElementById("class" + cls + "Supply").innerHTML = window["class" + cls + "Supply"];
    };
};
```

See [#1441532](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the) for other ways you might access those variables.

And don't use `class` as a variable/parameter name -- it's reserved.

Comment: Bleeding to global scope is bad

Comment: @Rajesh You many want to bring that up to OP then. Based on their question they appear to be wanting to change global variable values and condensing that into a single function.

Comment: @Rajesh I agree. This design has code smell all over it, but fixing that was not within the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function classClickSell(input, node) {
    if (input >= 1) {
        cash += input;
        document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = cash;
        --input;
        document.getElementById(node).innerHTML = input;
        return input;
    };
};

classClickSell(10, "classASupply");
```

If `classASupply` is actually global, and you need a potential decrement to stick after the function call, then you can just assign it to the return value of the above function, i.e.

```
var classASupply = 10;
classASupply = classClickSell(10, "classASupply");
```