# How to access variables inside function based on string variable representation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following function

```
function myFunction(){
var foo="My Foo String";
}
```

I would like to access my variable in a following way

```
function myFunction(){
var foo="My Foo String";
console.log(SOMETHINGIDONOTKNOWABOUT["foo"]);
}
```

I know in javascript its possible to use window["yourvariablename"] to access it, but I am interested to access function variable in similar way, therefor 
[Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the) is not a duplicate.
Eval is not correct answer for me.

Comment: I'm finding it very difficult to figure out what you're asking here. Can't you just use `foo`?

Comment: no I cant, because the variable is called dynamically. It comes as a string representation inside an object

Comment: You cannot access local variables in one function from a context outside that function. From inside the function, you can access the variables by name but not dynamically in any way analogous to `window["someName"]`.

Comment: `eval` is the *only* answer for accessing local variables by name. If you don't want to do that (and indeed, you should not), then **don't access local variables by name**. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Pointy Well Its the same function. I want to access it from inside my function. I just have no idea about how to access all variables that are inside the function in the same way as window["variablename"] works

Comment: There is no good way to do it. You can use the `[ ]` to access object properties dynamically, which is what `window["someName"]` involves, but there is no object to reference that way in the case of local variables. (It's possible with `eval()`, but there's generally no good reason for it and it has serious performance implications if you care about stuff like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Dynamic variables are really annoying to debug and optimize by the browser.

Use a set, a map, create a class for it, or even a simple object to store things you want to be able to access with a string.

```
function myFunction() {
    var myData = {
        "foo": "My foo string"
    };
    console.log( myData[ "foo" ] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question properly, you should use `foo` without quotes:

```
window[foo]
```

Just note that putting values on the global scope is a bad practice.

Comment: I do not think its correct answer as my variable is inside a function therefore I cant access it using window[]

Answer (score 0):

Is the following snippet the kind of things you are trying to achieve?

If you want to use a variable as an array element name, you don't have to use quotes. i.e. `array["foo"]` should be `array[foo]` if `foo` is a variable.

```js
var array = [];
array['foo'] = 'bar';

// Code #1
function myFunction(element) {
  console.log(array[element]);
}
myFunction('foo');

// Code #2
function myFunction() {
  element = 'foo';
  console.log(array[element]);
}
myFunction();
```

Hope it helps, in any way.

Comment: @trixo But where is defined your array? I assumed it was global. I added another code, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, I havent noticed your comment.There is no array. You can use window["variableName"] to access window variables with a string representing variable name.