# Is it possible to create a variable using user-defined name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to create a variable using a user-defined name in JavaScript?
I tried writing var a.value, where a is the id of the text field where the user will enter the variable name.

Comment: This is possible, yes. Can you add any attempts at solving the problem on your own?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an object with all your user-defined variables.

```js
const VAR_NAME = 'myVar'
const VAR_VALUE = 'myValue'

var obj = {
  [VAR_NAME]: VAR_VALUE
}

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj[VAR_NAME])
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to create a variables using user-defined name. 
take this example.

```js
var var_name = 'test_var';
const n = 120;
this[var_name] = n;
alert("printing using this[var_name]: "+this[var_name]);
alert("printing using test_var: "+test_var);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>test</title>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```