# loop over more then one different arrays with different array name

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I do that? In PHP I have the $$name form for doing that but in js I don't know how to solve this.

```
...
// rest of the code
var books = [
 {'h':'book 1','i':[ {'s':'1','w':'some text'}, {'s':'2','w':'other text'} ] }
];
var infos = [
 {'h':'HERE','i':[ {'h':'something','i':[ {'v':[{'g':1,'b':0}],'h':'text X','a':['bla','bla', 'bla']}]} ] }
];

var arrNames = ['books','infos'];

let z = document.getElementById('output');
for( i=0;i<arrNames.length;i++ ){
  arr = localStorage.getItem(arrNames[i]).split(','); // doesnt work :(
  html += arr[0]['h']+'<br>';
}
z.innerHTML = html;
```

output should to be:

```
book 1
HERE
```

but how?

### Solution Update:

thx @ Heretic Monkey and his [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the)

```
arr = window[arrNames[i]][j]['h'];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access a javascript variable using a string that contains the name of the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441532/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-javascript-variable-using-a-string-that-contains-the)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your comment, "doesnt work," do you mean that `.getItem()` or `.split()` does not work? If `.getItem()` returns `null`, `.split()` will not work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was tagged with `jQuery`? I removed it

Comment: why not just an old for loop? `for(let i = 0; i < <one of the 2 arrays>.length; i++) { console.log(books[i], infos[i]) }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey thx...thats it! can you set that as solution to get your point? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `localStorage` variables can only store Strings. So when you get that value, and split it, you have now broken it up into an Array of Strings. Here is an example to clarify.

```js
var local = {};
local.books = JSON.stringify([{
  'h': 'book 1',
  'i': [{
    's': '1',
    'w': 'some text'
  }, {
    's': '2',
    'w': 'other text'
  }]
}]);
local.infos = JSON.stringify([{
  'h': 'HERE',
  'i': [{
    'h': 'something',
    'i': [{
      'v': [{
        'g': 1,
        'b': 0
      }],
      'h': 'text X',
      'a': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla']
    }]
  }]
}]);

var arrNames = ['books', 'infos'];

var z = document.getElementById('output');
var html = ""
arrNames.forEach(function(elem) {
  var arr = local[elem].split(",");
  console.log(arr);
  html += arr[0]['h'] + '<br>';
});
z.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

You can see that `.split()` is doing what is needed, and you see the following in console:

```
[
  "[{\"h\":\"book 1\"",
  "\"i\":[{\"s\":\"1\"",
  "\"w\":\"some text\"}",
  "{\"s\":\"2\"",
  "\"w\":\"other text\"}]}]"
]
```

I suspect you need to Parse the String back into Variables. Consider the following.

```js
var local = {};
local.books = JSON.stringify([{
  'h': 'book 1',
  'i': [{
    's': '1',
    'w': 'some text'
  }, {
    's': '2',
    'w': 'other text'
  }]
}]);
local.infos = JSON.stringify([{
  'h': 'HERE',
  'i': [{
    'h': 'something',
    'i': [{
      'v': [{
        'g': 1,
        'b': 0
      }],
      'h': 'text X',
      'a': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla']
    }]
  }]
}]);

var arrNames = ['books', 'infos'];

var z = document.getElementById('output');
var html = ""
arrNames.forEach(function(elem) {
  var temp = JSON.parse(local[elem]);
  console.log(temp);
  html += temp[0]['h'] + '<br>';
});
z.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

For your code, you might consider taking it further and making helper functions.

```js
function setLocal(index, value) {
  localStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(value));
  return JSON.stringify(value);
}

function getLocal(index) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(index));
}

var arrNames = ['books', 'infos'];

var z = document.getElementById('output');
var html = ""
arrNames.forEach(function(elem) {
  var obj = getLocal(elem);
  console.log(obj);
  html += obj[0]['h'] + '<br>';
});
z.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

See More:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: interesting ways for that problem....thx

Answer (score -1):

You can use lodash zip function

```
_.zip(['a', 'b'], [1, 2], [true, false]);
```

In your case it should look like

```
_.zip(books, infos );
```

[here is documentation page](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip)

Comment: sry no. thats a solution for a future problem :) thx too!